# retrieve dynamic layout textview value?

Tags: android, android-layout, parse-platform

i followed this guid line to successfully created my dynamic layout

http://android-er.blogspot.tw/2014/01/get-text-from-dynamically-added-view.html
however, i have problem on getting the value from it. My idea is to add an button and when i press the button it saved all the dynamic layout textview value to parse.com

can anyone help me with this? 
thanks

xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:hint="Time of the Event"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/time"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time"
    android:text="Add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_toFriends_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:text="Next" />


 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/time_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/next_toFriends_button"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
 </LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
public class CreateEvent_time_Activity extends FragmentActivity {
 EditText mDate;
 EditText mTime;
 Button mButtonAdd;
 LinearLayout container;
 Button mButtonNext;
 protected String mObjectId;
 protected String Time;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_time_event);



  mDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);

 mDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public  void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
        mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(CreateEvent_time_Activity.this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month,
                    int day) {
                mDate.setText(month +"/"+day+"/"+ year);
            }

        }, mYear,mMonth, mDay);
        mDatePicker.setTitle("select date");
        mDatePicker.show();

    }
});
  mTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
  mTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(CreateEvent_time_Activity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                     mTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, false);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
  mButtonAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
  container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.time_container);
  mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                  (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_row,null);
         TextView dateout = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.dateout);
         TextView timeout = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.timeout);
        dateout.setText(mDate.getText().toString());
        timeout.setText(mTime.getText().toString());
        String time=dateout.getText().toString();

        Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);

            }
        });
        container.addView(addView);



    }


});
  mButtonNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_toFriends_button);
  mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent intent=getIntent();
          mObjectId=intent.getStringExtra("mobjectId");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstants.CLASS_Shopinfo);
        query.getInBackground(mObjectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject event, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null){



                    // this is where i want to store the data to parse.com

                }else {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateEvent_time_Activity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }

            }
        });



    }
});


 }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a code snip below how to add dynamically in layout :

```
 addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView
                        .findViewById(R.id.remove);
                addView.setTag(tag);
                buttonRemove.setTag(tag);
                dynamicLayoutsTags.add(tag);
                Container.addView(addView);
                tag++;
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent())
                        // .removeView(addView);
                        Integer removeTag = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        View deleteView = Container.findViewWithTag(removeTag);
                        Container.removeView(deleteView);
                        dynamicLayoutsTags.remove(removeTag);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```